# MvvmCross iOS presenter IMvxTouchView.ViewModel is null

Tags: mvvmcross

I am working on some project that involves MvvmCross. For iOS, I use my custom presenter that inherits from MvxTouchViewPresenter.

```
    public override void Show(IMvxTouchView view)
    {

     var viewController = view as UIViewController;

     if (viewController == null)
             throw new MvxException("Passed in IMvxTouchView is not a           UIViewController");
     if (_masterNavigationController == null)
             ShowFirstView(viewController);
     else
             _masterNavigationController.PushViewController(viewController, true /*animated*/);

     var myviewmodel = view.ViewModel;
     //Do some staff for myviewmodel

     }
```

My problem is that in most cases myviewmodel is null at that moment. It is created but later on ... when viewController is loaded. It looks like a timing problem... The interesting fact is this code worked perfectly at my previous MvvmCross project.

I also tried to use :

```
     var myviewmodel = view.ReflectionGetViewModel ();
```

Unfortunately the result was the same :(
Anyone having an idea how to fix or work around this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MvvmCross creates the ViewModel as part of `base.ViewDidLoad()` within your `ViewController` - so if `ViewDidLoad` has not been called then there won't be a `ViewModel` yet.

Based on this:

- you could try to trigger the `View` to be loaded - that would cause `ViewDidLoad` to fire? (The easiest way to do this is just to try to reference the `View`).
- or you could trick MvvmCross into loading the `ViewModel` a little bit early - to do this, call the `OnViewCreate` extension method from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.cs#L18

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response and great explanation, Stuart! I'll try it! :)